# FormatNumber() always 2 decimal

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, formatting

I'm trying to show a number with 2 decimals, and no thousand "," mark.

I have tried:

```
%%[

Set @PointBalance = 2300    
Set @FormatPoint = FormatNumber(@PointBalance,"N2")

]%%
```

This gives `2,300.00`.

Does anyone have some good documentation on how to use this function? The one on ExactTarget's documentation site is very lacking.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Divide()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Divide) function first and then use [FormatNumber()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#FormatNumber):

```
%%[
var @PointBalance, @FormatPoint

set @PointBalance = AttributeValue("PointBalance")
set @PointBalance = iif(not empty(@PointBalance),Divide(@PointBalance,100),0)
set @FormatPoint = FormatNumber(@PointBalance,"N2")

]%%
<br>FormatPoint: %%=v(@FormatPoint)=%%
```

If you find the SFMC documentation lacking, take the time to provide feedback at the bottom of the SFMC help page.  I've found them pretty responsive to that kind of feedback.

Most of the SFMC infrastructure is built on Microsoft products -- C# and SQL-Server.  Those are good places to start for reference:

[Standard Numeric Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Custom Numeric Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Found out my solution was to use [Format(](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Format)) instead.

```
%%[

Set @FormatPoint = Format(@PointBalance,"0.00")

]%%
```